# only last pending intent being set

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I have a broadcast receiver class that goes into an arraylist and sets multiple pending intents based on the time for each object although only the last pending intent set is showing up after boot i use a different value of count to ensure that request codes are different but only the last pending intent set in my loop still shows

```
public class AutoStartNotifyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
ArrayList<appointment> myArray;

 private final String BOOT_COMPLETED_ACTION = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED";

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

  if(intent.getAction().equals(BOOT_COMPLETED_ACTION)){


        FileInputStream input = null;
        ObjectInputStream inputob = null;
        try {
            input = context.getApplicationContext().openFileInput("app.ser");   
            inputob = new ObjectInputStream(input);

             myArray = (ArrayList<appointment>) inputob.readObject(); 

            inputob.close();
            input.close();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

      int count = 0;
      for(appointment cals: myArray)
      {
         if(cals.gettimeofappt()>current.getTimeInMillis())
         {
          count ++;
          Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);

          pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, count, myIntent, 0);


       AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


       alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cals.gettimeofappt(), pendingIntent);    
         }
      }





  }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's in the nature of a `PendingIntent` that they get reused in situations like this.  From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html):

> A PendingIntent itself is simply a reference to a token maintained by the system describing the original data used to retrieve it...
>
> The parts of the Intent that are used for matching are the same ones defined by Intent.filterEquals. If you use two Intent objects that are equivalent as per Intent.filterEquals, then you will get the same PendingIntent for both of them.

In the case of your loop, the `Intent`s are identical (from a filtering standpoint), so the `PendingIntent` gets reused - you only get one of them.

The solution to your problem is on the same documentation page:

> If you truly need multiple distinct PendingIntent objects active at the same time (such as to use as two notifications that are both shown at the same time), then you will need to ensure there is something that is different about them to associate them with different PendingIntents. This may be any of the Intent attributes considered by Intent.filterEquals, or different request code integers supplied to getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int), getActivities(Context, int, Intent[], int), getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int), or getService(Context, int, Intent, int).

Comment: but i do have a different request code i increment count

Comment: Sorry, missed `count` there. And only the last PendingIntent set in your loop gets delivered?

Comment: correct @String let me post my AlarmService.class that works with the actual notification